# Vertex AI Airflow Operators don't render XCom pulls (specifically CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator)

Tags: airflow, jinja2, batch-processing, airflow-2.x, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to run a batch predict job task using the Vertex AI Airflow Operator `CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator`. This requires pulling a model id from XCom which was pushed by a previous custom container training job. However, `CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator` doesn't seem to render Xcom pulls as expected.

I am running Airflow 2.3.0 on my local machine.

My code looks something like this:

```py
batch_job_task = CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator(
        gcp_conn_id="gcp_connection",
        task_id="batch_job_task",
        job_display_name=JOB_DISPLAY_NAME,
        model_name="{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='model_conf')['model_id'] }}",
        predictions_format="bigquery",
        bigquery_source=BIGQUERY_SOURCE,
        region=REGION,
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        machine_type="n1-standard-2", 
        bigquery_destination_prefix=BIGQUERY_DESTINATION_PREFIX,
```

This results in a value error when the task runs:

```
ValueError: Resource {{ ti.xcom_pull(key='model_conf')['model_id'] }} is not a valid resource id.
```

The expected behaviour would be to pull that variable by key and render it as a string.

I can also confirm that I am able to see the model id (and other info) in XCom by navigating there in the UI. I attempted using the same syntax with `xcom_pull` with a `PythonOperator` and it works.

```py
def print_xcom_value(value):
    print("VALUE:", value)

print_xcom_value_by_key = PythonOperator(
        task_id="print_xcom_value_by_key", python_callable=print_xcom_value,
        op_kwargs={"value": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='model_conf')['model_id'] }}" },
        provide_context=True,
        )

> [2022-12-15, 13:11:19 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - VALUE: 3673414612827265024
```

`CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator` does not accept `provide_context` as a variable. I assumed it would render xcom pulls by default since xcom pulls are used in the `CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator` in an example on the Airflow docs ([link here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_modules/tests/system/providers/google/cloud/vertex_ai/example_vertex_ai_batch_prediction_job.html)).

1. Is there any way I can provide context to this Vertex AI Operator to pull from the XCom storage?
2. Is something wrong with the syntax that I am not seeing? Anything I a misunderstanding [in the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/vertex_ai/batch_prediction_job/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.vertex_ai.batch_prediction_job.CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator)?

UPDATE:
One thing that confuses me is that `model_name` is a templated field according to the Airflow docs ([link here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/vertex_ai/batch_prediction_job/index.html)) but the field is not rendering the XCom template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set `render_template_as_native_obj=True` in your DAG definition?
What version of `apache-airflow-providers-google` do you use?

====

From OP:
Your answer was a step in the right direction.

The solution was to upgrade `apache-airflow-providers-google` to the latest version (at the moment, this is 8.6.0). I'm not able to pinpoint exactly where in the changelog this fix is mentioned.

Setting `render_template_as_native_obj=True` was not useful for this issue since it rendered the id pulled from XCom as an `int`, and I found no proper way to convert it to `str` when passed into `CreateBatchPredictionJobOperator` in the `model_name` arg.

Comment: I just set this in the DAG instance but I am receiving the same error:

`ValueError: Resource {{ ti.xcom_pull(key='model_conf', task_ids='train_custom_job_in_vertex_ai')['model_id'] }} is not a valid resource id.
`

The PythonOperator that prints the XCom value still works with no problems. 

As for the second question, I am using `apache-airflow-providers-google` version 6.8.0. I will try bumping this version up.